# Navigation Button not working CSS

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navigationbar

My navigation button is not working. (Menu is not opening).

I have included bootstrap `js` file too, but then also it is not working.

[See the Demo](http://jainvidhya.co.in/tindex.php)

Comment: Please specify your problem with the details for make it more understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

I suggest you to make change the following script source :

```
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Change it to  -

```
<script src="/index/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/index/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js">
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, it really helped me. One more question, when I click link of the menu bar why it doesn't collapse?

Comment: I request you to accept the answer by clicking the tick icon. Let me know if the change is live on the demo provided.

Comment: I had a look on the demo. Bootstrap doesn't hide it by default. You need to trigger a event on click to hide the nav.